# gdb list error "No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

I'm currently running a file manager program that abruptly crashed with a segmentation fault and dumped a core file. So I used gdb to debug the core file as:

```
gdb /path/to/executable /path/to/core
```

The program which I was running is written in C++. When I ran GDB and tried to print the source lines using "list", I got the following error:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000554286 in 
MyFSEventManager::AddEvent(wxFileSystemWatcherEvent&) ()
#1  0x00000000005ab2e8 in 
MyGenericDirCtrl::OnFileWatcherEvent(wxFileSystemWatcherEvent&) ()

(gdb) f 0
#0  0x0000000000554286 in 
MyFSEventManager::AddEvent(wxFileSystemWatcherEvent&) ()
(gdb) l
1    /build/glib2.0-prJhLS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./glib/gmain.c: No such file or directory.
```

Why does gdb say this **"/build/glib2.0-prJhLS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./glib/gmain.c: No such file or directory."** I do not hit this issue with some other programs that I've debugged using gdb.

The operating system used is Ubuntu 16.04 running on Oracle virtual box. I think may be the gdb symbols were not loaded. I'm not sure why since I compiled the program using the "-g" option. I really need to know the source lines where the code crashes via gdb.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: changes after suggestions from Employed Russian**

I was compiling my main using "-g" option and linking it to "existing" object files which were obviously not compiled using "-g" so when the core dumped, I could not see the source for these files. So I went ahead and recompiled those files with "-g" option and reproduced the core dump. It's able to show me the source lines now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does gdb say this "/build/glib2.0-prJhLS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./glib/gmain.c: No such file or directory."

Because you *really* don't have that file on your system.

> I think may be the gdb symbols were not loaded

GDB *did* load debug symbols for glib, but not for your main executable.

> I'm not sure why since I compiled the program using the "-g" option.

Since we don't have your compile and link lines, we can't tell exactly what's wrong, but some of the common issues are:

1. You have a "stray" `-s` or `-Wl,-s` on your link line (this strips debug info from the resulting binary).
2. You have `-g` when compiling your `main.c`, but not when compiling the source in which `MyFSEventManager::AddEvent()` is defined

P.S.

> `(gdb) bt`

This doesn't seem to be the complete output from `bt` command. Always try to paste complete outputs as it makes helping easier :)

Comment: There are 68 traces in the bt output. Pasting them all here would be cumbersome and make it confusing for all. So I did not post them. Let me check my make file to see if I have -s or -Wl,-s options accidentally being used.

Comment: @paratrooper "There are 68 ..." -- that actually could be quite relevant (you may have stack overflow). My point stands: by omitting information you make it harder to help you.

Comment: Based on what you mentioned above I just now cross checked my make file and Boom. You're absolutely right. I was compiling my main using "-g" option and linking it to "existing" object files which were obviously not compiled using "-g" so when the core dumped, I could not see the source for these files. So I went ahead and recompiled those files with "-g" option and reproduced the core dump. It's able to show me the source lines now. I'm accepting your answer